# xUnit DataAttribute with disposable data

Tags: c#, idisposable, xunit.net

I am writing some integration tests where we have multiple hardware devices connected to a computer, and we run the test for each device separately. I made a custom `DataAttribute` that scans for the devices and did the whole `SupportsDiscoveryEnumeration` thingy to prevent access to the devices during test discovery.

But now I'm dealing with the following issue: how do I dispose my devices? At first I did basically this:

```cs
yield return device;
device.Dispose();
```

But then it turned out that `DataAttribute.GetData()` is completely enumerated BEFORE running any tests, so my device ended up being disposed before the test.

So at this point I don't know where I can dispose of my connection. Especially with physical hardware it is important to properly close the connection. Is there any kind of extension point where I can release data generated by a `DataAttribute`?

Comment: Have the `DataAttribute` yield `Func`s, then use a `using device = connect() { ... }` in the body of your Test Method.

Comment: @RubenBartelink That would move the responsibility of initializing and disposing the instrument to each and every single the tests, which is exactly something I want to avoid.

Comment: I get that, but it solves your problem with 1 LOC. The fact that this is possible is very likely why it's not implemented yet. IIRC someone logged an issue about supporting this on the xunit github recently - might be worth making sure it covers your desires/needs.

Comment: @RubenBartelink The actual instrument setup is a bit more involved and also requires more than one thing to be disposed. Can you provide a link to that issue?

Comment: tried alphabeting `xunit theory dispose site:github.com` and got this workaround https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2403#issuecomment-944990842
Bottom line is you should keep this simple - if you have multiple things to be disposed then maybe aggregate them as a single Fixture and just use a `using`.

Answer (score 1):

if your program does not have asynchronous code you can use `IDisposable` interface and if you are using asynchronous, then you need to use `IAsyncLifetime`.

I provide two examples if it helps:

```
public class MyTestClassUnitTests : IDisposable
{
    public MyTestClassUnitTests ()
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // You unit test
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Teardown
        // device.Dispose();
    }

}
```

And for asynchronous, you need to implement IAsyncLifetime, as simplified following example, and remember in this case to add await for your async methods:

```
public class MyTestClassUnitTests : IAsyncLifetime
{
    public MyTestClassUnitTests()
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // You unit test
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        // Initial first time setup
    }

    public async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        // Teardown
    }
}
```

So you need to put `device.Dispose();` in `DisposeAsync()` method.

The idea here is that the disposal will run when the testing method is done with the test in tear down area. If I have misunderstood something please let me know so I can adjust my answer. Hope it helps.